# Passing variables to in IN statement in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to pass a variable amount of numbers to a stored procedure to limit the output from it.  Let's say I have 6 departments numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.  I would like the user to input any variety of those numbers.  So they might choose 1, 3, 6 or just 2, 4, or just 3, or whatever they want to see.  Can that be passed like a variable into an IN statement in the WHERE clause of a stored procedure?  If not, how else might one do this? I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Placeholders can only represent SINGLE values. you can't pass in multiple values in a single placeholder, e.g. `WHERE foo IN (?)` and passing in `1,2,3` will be executed as if it was written `WHERE foo = '1,2,3'`.  You can't use a "pre" prepared statement when you have arbitrary numbers of placeholders. You have to dynamically build your query string with as many placeholders as you have values, then pass them in with a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: One option is to convert the comma separated string of numbers to a temp table, then join or otherwise use that temp table in your query.  One way of doing it: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/584680/Using-comma-separated-value-parameter-strings-in-S

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: If you are using Postgres, pass an array and use `= any()`

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far.  Using Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A universal and robust SQL way of passing an array of values to a stored procedure would require multiple statements.

1. Insert your values into a (temporary) table.
2. Call your stored procedure which should contain joining logic to this table.
3. Remove recently added values from the table (if necessary)

You may want to enclose these statements into a transaction.